# puzzle game: how do i check if a sortable list item is in the correct place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a 3x3 puzzle game with Javascript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = populate;

    var imgArray = new Array("images/Untitled-0.png","images/Untitled-1.png","images/Untitled-2.png","images/Untitled-3.png","images/Untitled-4.png","images/Untitled-5.png","images/Untitled-6.png","images/Untitled-7.png","images/Untitled-8.png");

    var usedImg = new Array()

    var itemArray = new Array ("item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8")

    var div = document.getElementById("pieces");

    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

    function populate(){



        for (i=0; i<list.length;i++){

                var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);//generates a random #

                var img = new Image(); // creates a new image object
                img.src = imgArray[randomNum]; //source of the image is based on the random # and correlating item in imgArray

                do {
                    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
                    img.src = imgArray[randomNum]; //generates a new number
                } while (usedImg[img.src]); // but only if the source of the image is in used images


                usedImg[img.src] = true; //copies img.src to used image

                var imgPlace=document.createElement('img'); //instruct it to create an img tag
                imgPlace.src=img.src; //defines source

                var item = list[i]

                list[i].id = itemArray[randomNum];


                list[i].appendChild(imgPlace);

        };


        $( function() {
            $( "#pieces" ).sortable({
                cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
            });
            $( "#pieces" ).disableSelection();
          } );

        do {list[0].className = "ui-state-disabled"}
        while (list[0].id = "item0")
};
</script>
```

I've set it so the images randomly populate the `<li>` tags in the HTML when the page is loaded (ex. random tag is given an `id="item0"` and given the image `src="untitled-0"`) Those items can be sorted by dragging the images on the page using the `sortable()` JQueryUI. As it is, when a piece is moved to a particular space all the other pieces are shifted accordingly. I'd like to build it so that when a piece is in the correct `<li>` slot it is made unsortable. And, ideally, it would become sortable again when clicked.

The most simple approach seemed to write a line of code for each piece. I have tried

```
if (list[0].id = "item0") {
 list[0].className = "ui-state-disabled"}
```

as well as

```
do {list[0].className = "ui-state-disabled"}
    while (list[0].id = "item0")
```

with the same result, after `function populate`, regardless of its `id`, `list[0]` is immediately made `unsortable`. I'm still learning, but this has really got me stumped. any help would be appreciated.

the generated html:

```
<ul id="pieces" class="ui-sortable">

  <li id="item5" class="ui-state-disabled ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-5.png"></li>
  <li id="item3" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-3.png"></li>
  <li id="item6" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-6.png"></li>
  <li id="item1" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-1.png"></li>
  <li id="item2" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-2.png"></li>
  <li id="item7" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-7.png"></li>
  <li id="item4" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-4.png"></li>
  <li id="item0" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-0.png"></li>
  <li id="item8" class="ui-sortable-handle"><img src="file:///E:/Puzzle/images/Untitled-8.png"></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to disable the item for sorting, when you can move another element before it, which implicitly changes the position of the item you just fixed.

Comment: Unless, you are already know the middle piece, and as you solve the rest of the puzzle, you'd like that piece to stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

When you use single *equals* character  `=` you are assigning new value to your `list[0].id`, not comparing it. Try:

```
if (list[0].id === "item0") {
   list[0].className = "ui-state-disabled"
}
```

Comment: just tried this, as a do/while statement it had the same affect. As an if/then statement it had no affect at all.

Comment: In that case, could you please clone your generated `<ul>` HTML from browser and paste it to your answer?

Comment: edited my question with the generated html from the do/while statement

   do{list[0].className = "ui-state-disabled"}
            while (list[0].id == "item0");

Comment: All right, again. Check my edit. Thing is, the only difference between `do while` and `while` is that the first one fires once no matter what condition you give it, so it was setting the class anyway.

Comment: that's really good to know, thank you! And thanks for the edits. I changed it to a simple `while` statment, and it's not initially applying the class change anymore, but it's still not applying it when I move the piece into position.

Comment: That's whole another question, as it involves adding function called on jquery-ui `drop` event. In your code, that condition is executed only once, `onload`, because only there you call your `populate` function, and it is inside of it.

Comment: I feel really dumb for not seeing that was still in my populate function. Cool, I haven't tried the drop function yet, so I'll mess around with that. Thanks for help!

Comment: I feel dumb about not figuring out the `do while` part at first, don't worry, it comes with a job once a while :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the disabling in response to the jQueryUI `stop` event, to be passed to the `sortable` method, like this:

```
sortable({
    stop: function() {
        // Iterate over all the items and check their positions
        $('li').each(function (i) {
            // Turn disabled class on or off, depending on position:
            $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-disabled', $(this).data('num') === i);
        });
    }
})
```

There are also other improvements you could apply. For instance, the way you a select random sequence can be improved so you don't need to retry until you pick an unused number.

Note that although you can disable items for dragging, they will still move if you move items across those that are disabled: this will change the position of those disabled items as well.

Here is a working snippet (with different image locations: adapt as needed):

```js
$(function () {
    var ids = [];
    $('li').each(function (i) {
        ids.push(i);
    });
    $('li').each(function (i) {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);// pick random index
        // translate it to original index, and remove
        randomNum = ids.splice(randomNum, 1)[0]; 
        // Assign id of chosen image to list item
        $(this).data('num', randomNum)
            // Assign chosen image to a new img element and append it to item
            .append($('<img>')
                .prop('height', 20).prop('width', 20) // size set for demo only
                // TODO: Adapt image location to 'images/Untitled-' + randomNum + '.png'
                .prop('src', 'https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/fall05/cs340/mp2images/' 
                              + randomNum + '.gif'));
    });

    $( "#pieces" ).sortable({
        cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
        stop: function() {
            // Iterate over all the items and check their positions
            $('li').each(function (i) {
                // Turn disabled class on or off, depending on position:
                $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-disabled', $(this).data('num') === i);
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.ui-state-disabled { background-color: #ccc }
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<ul id="pieces">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```